# navbar Auto-Hiding when onclick just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this website http://www.engagia.ma That Contain a responsive navbar , That it work properly in all browser except google chrome(mobile) the navbar appear and hide automatically on one click , and for educational purposes i want to know how to fix this error on chrome mobile browser? knowing that this website include already : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`
 Thank you

[image]

Comment: It works fine on my Chrome, which version are you on?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch version 61 please try to test in Google Chrome on Mobile not Desktop version